# GSMComm error The value 105 is not part of the 7-bit default alphabet extension table

Tags: c#, gsm, sms-gateway

I develop SMS Gateway app, using GSMComm Lib. When read the message

```
SmsDeliverPdu data = (SmsDeliverPdu)pdu;
Output("Message: " + data.UserDataText);
```

it contains special character (send using autotext from BlackBerry phone)
and throws An exception of type System.ArgumentException occurred and was caught

Below is the log file:

```
Type : System.ArgumentException, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
Message : The value 105 is not part of the 7-bit default alphabet extension table.
Source : PDUConverter
Help link : 
ParamName : 
Data : System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal
TargetSite : Char SevenBitExtensionToChar(Byte)
Stack Trace :    at GsmComm.PduConverter.TextDataConverter.SevenBitExtensionToChar(Byte b)
   at GsmComm.PduConverter.TextDataConverter.SevenBitToString(String s, Boolean throwExceptions)
   at GsmComm.PduConverter.PduParts.DecodeText(Byte[] userData, Byte dataCodingScheme)
   at GsmComm.PduConverter.SmsPdu.get_UserDataText()
   at GTMP.PresentationTier.Win.SMSGateway.frmSMSGateway.ShowMessage(SmsPdu pdu)
   at GTMP.PresentationTier.Win.SMSGateway.frmSMSGateway.ReadMessage()
   at GTMP.PresentationTier.Win.SMSGateway.frmSMSGateway.frmSMSGateway_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e)
```

How to solve this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved.
I check the string contain 7bit character set or not using this regex:

```
"^[A-Za-z0-9 \\r\\n@£$¥èéùìòÇØøÅå\u0394_\u03A6\u0393\u039B\u03A9\u03A0\u03A8\u03A3\u0398\u039EÆæßÉ!\"#$%&amp;'()*+,\\-./:;&lt;=&gt;?¡ÄÖÑÜ§¿äöñüà^{}\\\\\\[~\\]|\u20AC]*$";
```

[source](http://frightanic.com/software-development/regex-for-gsm-03-38-7bit-character-set/)

code:

```
public static bool IsInputContainNonGSM7BitCharacterSet(string value)
{
    string GSM_7_BIT_CHARACTER_SET = " @£$¥èéùìòÇØøÅåΔ_ΦΓΛΩΠΨΣΘΞ^{}\\[~]|€ÆæßÉ!\"#¤%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?¡ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZÄÖÑÜ§¿abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzäöñüà";
    char letter = default(char);

    for (int i = 0; i < value.Length; i++)
    {
        letter = value[i];

        if (GSM_7_BIT_CHARACTER_SET.IndexOf(letter) == -1)
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello, i got the same problem but with the value of 15 and 99... I see that you did a regex for solve it but can you explain me better how you do the regex? I'm developing almost the same thing as you are, but I'm not an expert in coding yet, so I got a little stuck here... If you can help me I will appreciate! Thank you in advance.

Comment: @JoãoSilva I updated the answer, include my code to check message contain 7bit char or not, hope it help

Comment: @Willy can you update again of your question above how to solve it based on your answer using `SmsDeliverPdu data = (SmsDeliverPdu)pdu;
Output("Message: " + data.UserDataText);`

Answer (score -1):

Instead of using `data.UserDataText`, I used

```
TextDataConverter.SevenBitToString(TextDataConverter.OctetsToSeptetsStr((message.Data as SmsDeliverPdu).UserData), false)
```