# GSMComm error: The value 13 is not part of the 7-bit default alphabet extension table

Tags: c#

Application Through Exception when Reading SmS using GSM MODEM  and The Exception is :

The value 13 is not part of the 7-bit default alphabet extension table

```
            DataRow dr = dt.NewRow()
            SmsDeliverPdu data = (SmsDeliverPdu) pdu
            dr[0] = data.OriginatingAddress.ToString()
            dr[1] = data.SCTimestamp.ToString()
```

it contains special character

Below is the line where exception occur:

```
             dr[2] =data.UserDataText.ToString()
            dt.Rows.Add(dr)
```

Comment: what have you tried so far? and what is the expected behaviour?

Comment: i am trying to Read All messages from SIM using GSM modem Device

Comment: I am Using GSMcomm library for that

Comment: Possible duplicate of [GSMComm error The value 105 is not part of the 7-bit default alphabet extension table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20965174/gsmcomm-error-the-value-105-is-not-part-of-the-7-bit-default-alphabet-extension)

Comment: I search that too on stack overflow but that was not the case in my application

Comment: @kamran Are you sure? Your problem seems to be that you have a carriage return "\r" character in your input, which isn't allowed in GSM. This character is part of the regex that the linked answer checks.

Comment: when application reading sms  then it will through that exception i don t known whats is going on but i thing there is some messages in SIM that is was not supported by default alphabet extension